# Distinguishing between a hyperbola and a parabola in the projective plane

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. It is a standard result that in the projective plane $\mathbb{P}^2$, all the conics are equivalent to each other, unlike the affine algebraic case of $\mathbb{A}^2$ where we have 2 equivalence classes of conics - parabolas and hyperbolas. However, my professor mentioned something very vaguely about being able to distinguish between parabolas and hyperbolas in $\mathbb{P}^2$ by means of Bezout's Theorem. I have no clue what that means or how it is to be done. Can anyone throw any light in this regard?

(I agree that this question might be slightly open-ended, but this is all the information I have).

Comment: Without any further details, this appears to be a false statement. Instead of trying to guess, the best thing is to ask your professor what they meant.Can you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L\subset \mathbb{P}^2$ be the line at infinity (e.g. $L=\mathbb{P}^2\backslash\mathbb{A}^2$). There are two cases for how a smooth conic $C\subset \mathbb{P}^2$ can intersect $L$ if our field is algebraically closed:

1) $C\cap L$ is two reduced points (e.g. $L$ and $C$ intersect at two distinct points)

2) $C\cap L$ is one nonreduced point with multiplicity 2 (e.g. $L$ and $C$ are tangent at one point)

The first case is the case of a hyperbola and the second is the case of a parabola.

---

If the terminology doesn't seem to make sense, consider the case of a conic $C\subset\mathbb{P}^2_{\mathbb{R}}$ defined over $\mathbb{R}$. In this case, there are three possibilities. There are the two possibilities above, but there is also the third possibility that $L$ intersects $C$ at a complex point (e.g. $L$ doesn't intersect $C$ at a real point, but after base change to $\mathbb{C}$ you will see two complex points and fall under the first case above).

I claim that these three different ways the line $L$ can intersect our conic $C$ defined over $\mathbb{R}$ correspond to the case of a hyperbola, parabola, and ellipse respectively, and they coincide with the definitions given in high school algebra.